# Why ScrollBars is showing even though AutoSctoll is set to False?

Tags: vb.net

I have MDIContainer `frmMain` and `From1` as a Child

However, it seems when I move Form1 beyond the MIDContainer bounds the Vertical and Horizontal scrollbars appear even though I have set `AutoScroll = False`

```
'frmMain
        '
        Me.AutoScroll = False
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(9.0!, 20.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(2128, 1394)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.MenuStrip1)
        Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
        Me.IsMdiContainer = True
        Me.MainMenuStrip = Me.MenuStrip1
        Me.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 5, 4, 5)
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.Name = "frmMain"
        Me.Text = "Main Form"
        Me.MenuStrip1.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.MenuStrip1.PerformLayout()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the Scrollbars belong to Form? Did you check what is the Parent of a child Form in a MDI app?

Comment: then you need to over write the original code see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/819be1ea-b43f-447c-bb01-bf07ce36dcde/how-will-i-disable-the-scrollbars-in-mdi-parent?forum=winforms

Comment: Ensuring the child window can be navigated to and made fully visible is the job of the [MdiClient window](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MDIClient.cs,37), the one with the dark gray background.  There is no obvious way to make it stop show those scrollbars, this behavior is hard-baked in the OS.

Comment: @HansPassant So I believe there is no easy way.  as others suggested I may have to rewrite the code which is something not worth it and not planning to invest the time. I was looking for an easy fix and thought `AutoScroll = False` will do the job.

Comment: All the *magic* happens [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MDIClient.cs,109) (`cp.ClassName = "MDICLIENT";`). Read the notes you find right after. -- What happens next is `cp.Style |= NativeMethods.WS_VSCROLL | NativeMethods.WS_HSCROLL;`: Styles can be added or removed. It could be an *unexpected* move, though. Test with [SetWindowLongPtr()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw), see what happens.